# JSON.net Deserializing

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have a string which is JSON encoded. I'm also having C# class:

```
class Pupu{
    public static List<Pupu> plist = new List<Pupu>();
    public string user {get; set;}
    public string number {get; set;}
}


[{"user":"27FFBADD7284E5CB98EAC45559589E28FDDDC3AD","number":"62827"},{"user":"27FFBADD7284E5CB98EAC45559589E28FDDDC3AD","number":"30460"}, {"user":"0D27D44D40C5185423078B3C93B3E6B596AD21A0","number":"25143"}, {"user":"0D27D44D40C5185423078B3C93B3E6B596AD21A0","number":"22776"}, {"user":"27FFBADD7284E5CB98EAC45559589E28FDDDC3AD","number":"19755"}]
```

I am desirializing it with:

```
 plist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Pupu>>(stringAbove);
```

I am keep getting:

```
 Attempt to access the method failed: System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor();
```

Thanks, I'm looking for this for few hours now. (I'm pretty new to C#).

Comment: You cannot have an instance of class X inside class X's declaration.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's try to clean up your code:

```
public class Score
{
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}
```

and now you can deserialize the JSON into a list of scores:

```
List<Score> plist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Score>>(stringAbove);
```

and here's a full example:

```
public class Score
{
    public string user { get; set; }
    public string number { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var json = "[{\"user\":\"27FFBADD7284E5CB98EAC45559589E28FDDDC3AD\",\"number\":\"62827\"},{\"user\":\"27FFBADD7284E5CB98EAC45559589E28FDDDC3AD\",\"number\":\"30460\"}, {\"user\":\"0D27D44D40C5185423078B3C93B3E6B596AD21A0\",\"number\":\"25143\"}, {\"user\":\"0D27D44D40C5185423078B3C93B3E6B596AD21A0\",\"number\":\"22776\"}, {\"user\":\"27FFBADD7284E5CB98EAC45559589E28FDDDC3AD\",\"number\":\"19755\"}]";
        List<Score> plist = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Score>>(json);

        foreach (Score score in plist)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("user: {0}, number: {1}", score.user, score.number);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was my mistake it's same class name in actual file. Sorry

Comment: I missed public keyword. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you have missed a couple of things in your question. That's why I decided to post a full working example that you could run and adapt to your requirements.