# json.net with c sharp

Tags: c#, json.net

```
string jsondata = @"{""meta"":{""code"":200}}";
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsondata);
```

I have above json data and I created class for it. I have also deserialized it - how can I iterate this json variable

```
public class Meta
{
    public int code { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: the question is not clear....

Comment: OP wants to deserialize the json string to a .NET object. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534576/json-net-deserializing

Answer (score 1):

To Work with your code, you should user the typed convert

```
string jsondata = @"{""meta"":{""code"":200}}"; 
Meta json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Meta>(jsondata);
```

Then you can Acces all the members in the meta obj.

---

With normal .net json runtime you can deserialize a string

```
string jsondata = @"{""meta"":{""code"":200}}"
Meta meta = JsonHelper.JsonDeserialize<Meta>(jsondata);
```

For more info see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET

You need to have this code ofc

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Text;  
 /// <summary>
 /// JSON Serialization and Deserialization Assistant Class
 /// </summary>
 public class JsonHelper
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// JSON Serialization
     /// </summary>
     public static string JsonSerializer<T> (T t)
     {
         DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
         MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
         ser.WriteObject(ms, t);
         string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
         ms.Close();
         return jsonString;
     }  
     /// <summary>
     /// JSON Deserialization
     /// </summary>
     public static T JsonDeserialize<T> (string jsonString)
     {
         DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
         MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString));
         T obj = (T)ser.ReadObject(ms);
         return obj;
     }
 }
```